# Custom operator function for mathematic operation in Swift

Tags: swift

I want define a new function for Int, which I can do the same job like +, the function name is plus, as far as I see in the codes, I made no mistake but I believe I have to take some more steps that Swift accept this function as a math function, Swift throw me compiler error like this: ***can not find "plus"***
need help for overcome to issue, thanks.

```
extension Int {
    
    static func plus (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {

        return lhs + rhs
    }
    
}
```

---

use case:

```
 let value: Int = 1 plus 2
```

ps: I know that plus is under group of Int, but I want it be accessible alone.

Comment: Do you need exactly the syntax `1 plus 2`? There is no such syntax in Swift. You can't just invent something new...

Comment: You cannot use `plus` as an operator.

Comment: thanks for both to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use symbols to override operators like following. But you need to define **precedencegroup** first and then create **infix** operator. Infix operator works with left hand side and right hand side.

```
precedencegroup SumOperatorPrecedence {
    lowerThan: MultiplicationPrecedence
    higherThan: AdditionPrecedence
    associativity: left
    assignment: false
}

infix operator *&:SumOperatorPrecedence
extension Int {

    static func *&(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {
    
        return lhs + rhs
    
    }

}


let f = 2 *& 3
```

Comment: thanks but I do not want replace or override something, also your code does not work for "plus", also I want use function in extension not defining outside

Comment: plus won't work. What u are trying to achieve is called operator overloading

Comment: updated my answer @swiftPunk. Alphabets won't work as it is a limitation of swift

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a number with itself, then you can do this:

```
extension Int {

  func plus (rhs: Int) -> Int {

    return self + rhs
  }
}
```

Now, you can call it on any Integer. Like:

```
2.plus(rhs: 10) // prints 12
```

Comment: thanks, but that is an obvious use of a function, I was interested to 1 plus 2

Comment: @swiftPunk What do you want 1.plus(rhs: 2)?